# What is `+monthArray` in this Obj-C Doc?

Tags: objective-c

I am reading https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH4-SW1 and I am unfamiliar with the language construct that is:

`+monthArray` in the header filer and

```
+ monthArray
{
    if (!sharedMonthArray) {
        sharedMonthArray = [[MonthArray alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedMonthArray;
}
```

in the implementation file. Is `+monthArray` declaring a static constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a class method with the `id` return type omitted from the declaration. Identical to

```
+ (id) monthArray {
```

Legal but archaic style.